# From specific to relative humidity?

Tags: humidity

I was wondering if there is a way to obtain relative humidity from specific. My constraint is that I am not trying to solve a problem by hand. I am downloading data for a specific region, in order to construct a multi model for climate modelling. Unfortunately, I do not have access to any dataset that I want. The following variables have available datasets which I can use:
-specific humidity
-maximum and minimum air temperature
-mean daily wind speed at 10m
-vapour pressure (hPa)
-sum of precipitation (mm/day)
-potential evapotranspiration from a crop canopy (mm/day)
-total global radiation (KJ/m2/day)
Is there any equation that I can use to obtain relative humidity?

Comment: When you say "specific humidity", do you mean "dew point"? Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation

Comment: Probably better suited for physics stackexchange